# Opinion based questions

Tags: discussion

I was trying to find some (news/code) ressources on Machine learning and about to post a question on datascience.SE but a similar question has been asked before:

[What are your favorite sources for news about Machine Learning and Data Science?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/538/what-are-your-favorite-sources-for-news-about-machine-learning-and-data-science)

It also has been closed for the following reason:

"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

While I understand the explanation I still think the format was the problem but the content of the question is worth something. Can I slightly reword the question to include a well defined metrics and avoid the opinion based question ? (I don't want to look like i am trying to cheat the moderation)

Answer (score 3):

Yes in general you are welcome to reword a question and get it reopened. I think you might make this a more useful question by specifying what you are trying to understand better and what your key questions are.